# How do I get a SB X-Fi Xtreme Audio CA0110 working?

Tags: sound

Alsa does not support my (SB X-Fi Xtreme Audio CA0110) audio card as shown in [their web page](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix%3aVendor-Creative_Labs).

Now my question is how can I configure my audio driver without using ALSA? And should I waste my time trying to make this audio card work or it is simply impossible for linux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Development on ALSA's ctxfi driver generally is very plodding due to lack of open data sheets (so putting pressure on Creative to provide them without the mandatory NDA may help here). You may have better luck with a very recent ALSA snapshot at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/InstallingLinuxAlsaDriverModules or OSSv4.2 at http://www.4front-tech.com/developer/sources/testing/gpl/oss-v4.2-buildrc3-src-gpl.txt. Be aware that choosing the latter route requires significant time investment (but is possible).

Comment: i have updated my kernal, and now it is Kernal Linux 2.6.32-272 generic.and after this update the audio stopped working again.what should i do how can i get back the old kernal, should i do format and install ubuntu again ??

Comment: Can you clarify what you did to make audio work?

Answer (score 0):

`ubuntu-bug` fixes it till the next restart. Type `ubuntu-bug` in a Terminal window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and follow the program.

Comment: Can you provide more information? It's very strange that Apport would actually *fix* this sort of problem.