# How do I get an SB X-Fi Xtreme Audio CA0110 working again after a kernel update?

Tags: drivers, sound

I [asked a question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18015/how-do-i-get-a-sb-x-fi-xtreme-audio-ca0110-working) on how do I get an SB X-Fi Xtreme Audio CA0110 working three days ago. And they told me to install the Alsa driver modules from this website:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/InstallingLinuxAlsaDriverModules

This answer did work and my audio driver was working until I updated my kernel...

Now the new kernel is Linux 2.6.32-27 generic. How can I get the Alsa module driver to work on this new kernel?

Or at least, how can I go back to the old kernel?

I tried to run this command:

```
apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r)
```

And this is what I get:

> Couldn't find package linux-alsa-driver-modules-2.6.32-27-generic

Comment: you say that you have the audio ppa add to sources.list then do it again this command sudo apt-get install linux-alsa-driver-modules-$(uname -r) for the new kernel and see what happen

Comment: yes i did what you asked, and this is what happens:E: Couldn't find package linux-alsa-driver-modules-2.6.32-27-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've [poked Brad](https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-audio-dev/msg00167.html) (who has commit access to the [git tree](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git?p=bradf/alsa-driver-cod-lucid/.git;a=summary)) and asked for an ABI bump. Once he commits the change and kicks off the daily build, the next available linux-alsa-driver-modules for 10.04 from the ppa should resolve your issue.

Comment: can you help me again, another kernal update had happened and i need new audio driver.. please help